# cvAUC Error: unused argument (label.ordering = NULL)

Tags: r, label, prediction, evaluation, auc

Until a couple of days ago, I used to be able to compute AUC score via cvAUC package by the below code:

```r
install.packages("cvAUC")
library(cvAUC)

AUC(replicate(10, 0), replicate(10, 1), label.ordering = NULL)
```

I created two fake vectors for prediction and actual label. I could run this without any problems until a couple days ago. Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Try `cvAUC::AUC(replicate(10, 0), replicate(10, 1), label.ordering = NULL)`, does it give the same error? If not, then you likely have `AUC` from a different package loaded, and R is using that one instead.

Comment: @slamballais You are absolutely right, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

You have `AUC` loaded from multiple packages, and R is using the other one. Try using `::`:

```r
cvAUC::AUC(replicate(10, 0), replicate(10, 1), label.ordering = NULL)
```

***Additional information***

If you use `find(AUC)`, you'll see that multiple namespaces are linked to `AUC`. We can specify from which namespace you want to use `AUC` with the `::` operator: `cvAUC::AUC`.